# Reference Request: A book that explains the origin of the American political left & right

Tags: united-states, ideology, reference-request, political-science

In 2011 spring, in college, someone recommended a book to me. The book was assigned as a political science reading in an undergraduate introductory level political course they were taking at Johns Hopkins University. He said that the book explains how the American left & right (maybe democrat & republican I cannot remember) developed. I am trying to find that book now, but am having trouble.

Comment: How many years ago exactly?

Comment: perhaps the american political tradition https://www.amazon.com/American-Political-Tradition-Men-Made/dp/0679723153/

Comment: There are a *lot* of political science assigned reading texts out there. It would help to know the rough era (70s, 80s, 90s..?), whether is was an intro, upper form, or graduate class, and any more specific details you can dredge up.

Comment: The terminology has its origins in the seating arrangements that evolved naturally in the original French parliament and was copied in the U.S. and everywhere else after the terms acquired secondary meaning as a reference to an idea rather than a seating location. I don't think that this is what you are really asking about, although I'm not sure. I learned this from a European history textbook but it is widely known.

Comment: @JamesK 10 years ago. that might be it. I am not sure. the title does not ring a bell.

Comment: @TedWrigley 2011 undergraduate introductory level course